# Nontrivial example of a discontinuous real-valued convex function?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a real Hilbert space, and let $f\colon\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ be convex.

It's known that if $\mathcal{X}$ is *finite-dimensional*, then $f$ is also continuous.
However, if $\mathcal{X}$ is infinite dimensional, this result is no longer true, since there are discontinuous linear functionals (and linear functionals are convex).

I'd like to get a better intuition on this class of discontinuous, convex, real-valued functions, so I'm looking for more **nonlinear** examples. A simple affine example is constructed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215486/nonlinear-discontinuous-convex-function/1215596#comment8198596_1215596). However, that example is not incredibly enlightening since it is based off of the linear case. Are there other examples?

Comment: IIRC, an everywhere defined real-valued convex function on a Banach space is continuous if and only if locally bounded. This might help finding a nonlinear example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not sure I follow, since there are explicit examples of discontinuous linear functionals. For instance, in the space of polynomials over $[0,1]$ under the $\sup$ norm, the linear map $D\colon f\mapsto f'(1)$ is discontinuous, since it maps the bounded sequence $(x^k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ to the unbounded sequence $(k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Now that I think of it, I can't come up with an explicit example in a Hilbert space. However, it's a much stronger statement to say it's impossible.

Comment: One partial example (a convex function which is real-valued at a discontinuity, but also takes some extended-real values) is Example 9.43 in Bauschke & Combettes' book (vol. 2) . They construct a function $g$ and a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and $\lim g(x_n)=1\neq0=g(0)$.